# Is Salesforce DX compatible with Classic?

Tags: salesforcedx, ci

There is no answer in the documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Salesforce DX is a new approach to development, not a new interface. As such, it will support all the features that the org supports.

This means that you will be able to write Apex, Lightning and VF as you do in your current IDE but your workflow (git, jenkins, circle, etc) might change a lot (or a little) depending on the strategy you choose.

I think you might benefit from [this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/trails/sfdx_get_started) trailhead, to understand what Salesforce DX is (And what it isn't) and how to approach working with it.

Comment: So you can create classic scratch orgs then? I've been through the setup dx trailhead. although it seems great, this part wasn't clear to me. Thanks for the fast response

Comment: There is no such a thing as a "classic scratch org". An org is both classic and lightning. You can disable classic, if you want, by preventing profiles from being able to switch, but every org is capable of entering both classic and Lightning mode.

Comment: Also, if this post helped and you feel it answers your question, feel free to mark it as accepted so others can benefit.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, thanks. All the tutorials/trailhead are in lightning so i wasn't 100%. Best regards

Comment: I think one important thing to note here is that Salesforce has said that Dev Hub (the app that sits in your business org to manage DX) is only available in Lightning Experience. I am not sure if this is only during the beta or long term.

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP meant, though

Comment: @dsharrison the dev hub is available on Classic as well.

Answer (score 0):

SalesforceDX will be launched together with a new way to describe the platform's metadata. That's the only difference. It will work for the platform - doesn't matter if you are on Classic or Lightning.